# isDirty property in exchange

Tags: c#, exchange-server

I am trying to use the isDirty property for detecting whether an exchange mail folder has been modified or not.(including the sub content for example a mail has been put into this folder then it is considered modified)

What I don't know is that what are the limitation of this property and how exactly it works. I have read the documentation on MSDN for isDirty and it doesn't really help, all I know is that it returns whether an object has been modified or not

[Official explanation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.serviceobject.isdirty(v=exchg.80).aspx): Gets a value that indicates whether the object has been modified.

However I don't know does that mean the object has been modified since its creation? or last time accessed? or some other meaning. I don't know what is it been compared to when I extract that property. Can someone please elaborate that for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Managed API is a Client side library so the isDirty property is really only going to indicate if you have made changes to one of the client side properties of those objects. Eg if you reading a message, change the subject on that client side object but don't commit the changes to the server using the Update method then the client side object would be dirty.

If your stated aim is to "detecting whether an exchange mail folder has been modified or not" that's not the way to do it. I would suggest you look at PR_LOCAL_COMMIT_TIME_MAX (0x670a0040) and PR_DELETED_COUNT_TOTAL (0x670b0003) as documented in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn458788(v=exchg.150).aspx these properties will get updated when the underlying folder item collections are modified.

Cheers
Glen

Comment: hey glen I read through [your article](http://gsexdev.blogspot.ca/2012/03/how-to-sample-3-scanning-all-folders.html) on dev blog and [Incremental Change Synchronization API Definitions post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/exchangedev/archive/2008/03/27/incremental-change-synchronization-api-definitions.aspx) However I am still abit confused tell me if I understood it right? From my understanding that basically everytime I do a sync with the server or someone else do a sync with the server the PR_LOCAL_COMMIT_TIME_MAX changes into a new value? is that correct?

Comment: So if my local commit time value is different with server one that indicated someone else has committed to the server correct? Thus I require more sync on that particular folder?

Comment: From an EWS perspective that property will just tell you if the underlying folder Item Collection has been updated. EWS has its own Syncronizaiton operations like SyncFolderItems which you may want to look at. Your client actions don't really matter unless you changing something in that folder (eg adding a new item etc). This http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee160594(v=EXCHG.80).aspx is probably a better explanation of what happens with the prop.

Comment: Glen 1 question I want to ask is that If a content within the sub folder has been changed would the PR_LOCAL_COMMIT_TIME_MAX be updated on the parent folder?

Comment: No that property only will only be updated when items in that folder is updated. If your tracking across a whole folder tree you will need to track that property on every folder in the tree. Eg you could use a FindFolder with a Deep traversal to get the property on every folder within a tree. AFAIK none of the EWS notification or Sync operations bubble up like that, with notifications you have the option of subscribing to all folder in a tree.